# How to insert, change or remove a single table item in Tabris?

Tags: tabris

I'm trying to understand how to design this using Tabris.

My current design updates the tableview by setting a new list:
viewer.setInput(list);

This is not what I want as this refreshes always the entire table with a nasty refresh view behavior.
What I want is just to apply a single change to the table, so remove a tree item, change or insert. Just spend some time to get viewer.insert(...), remove(...) working.
The TreePath required for this call is what confuses me. Tried to create one I'm pretty sure it is not correct.

Does anyone has a good example or any other suggestions to get me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the TreeViewer.replace method. With this method you can change a single item.

Comment: Thanks Holger. Do you have any examples how to use? I can't get it to work. Again, I think I'm having issues understanding to provide the correct TreePath.